# How to target parents from elements with a class?

Tags: css

So, `.search-chat-search-btn > form { }` targets the form "inside" the element with class `.search-chat-search-btn`, but can I make it go the other way? As in, target the form that is outside `.search-chat-search-btn`?

```
<form>
    <button class="search-chat-search-btn"></button>
</form>
```

Apparently this is suppose to work, but it doesn't. Target every form that has a button.

```
form:has(> button) {
    display: inline;
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

(but then I just realised it's only supported in Safari, development version?)

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is - as yet - no parent selector; though - as you mention in your question - there is the [relational selector, `:has()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#relational), which is not yet implemented, in [Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't target a parent element in CSS. It's not possible (at least not yet). Also concerning `:has`, no major browser supports it yet.

**Update 2024**

`:has()` is now supported by all major browsers.

> Since December 2023, this feature works across the latest devices and
> browser versions. This feature might not work in older devices or
> browsers.

Comment: All major browsers seem to support it by now: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: @Ben you're right. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

> As in, target the form that is outside .search-chat-search-btn?

Based on the question, I assume you want to select style all the `form` that not inside the `.search-chat-search-btn`, then you probably looking for css `:not` pseudo-class

Maybe you are looking for [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) :

```css
:not(.search-chat-search-btn) form{
  color:blue
}
.search-chat-search-btn form{
color:red
}
```

```html
<div class='search-chat-search-btn'>
<form>Yes</form></div>
<form >Hello</form>
<form >Hello</form>
```

Comment: Not quite. I edited an example to my question.

Comment: @JAmes, I little confused, you want to select the button that outside the search-chat-search-btn or the form that doesn't has `button:search-chat-search-btn`?

Comment: Select all the forms that have a button with the class `search-chat-search-btn`